# Radial scaling towards an inner circle

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, transform, corel-draw

In an image, I want to shrink the light green ring (outside of the black inner circle) inward, radially, towards the edge of the inner circle (dark green). After the transform, the light green ring should be narrower, but still attached to the dark green edge around the inner black circle. The black circle remains static. Is there a way perform such a transformation in any common 2D graphics software? [edited for more clarity]

[image]

Comment: This sounds so simple that I suspect I *still* misunderstand even after your last edit. Why don't you just scale the light green circle? Or isn't it vector graphics? If the image you want to transform in reality is more complex than the example you show, can't you post the actual image you want to manipulate?

Comment: If I just scale the green ring towards a single center point, its inner edge will cross "into" the black circle, whereas what I want is for the light green ring to remain "wrapped" around the black circle.

Comment: **Layer** the light green area *behind* the black area. Then it "won't go into" the black area.

Comment: I get it now. The misunderstanding is that because you tagged your question with *adobe-illustrator* and you post an image which looks like vector, we assume that you have *vector shapes*! In reality you have a *raster image* right?

Comment: But I want to preserve the content of the light green ring. If I layer it behind the black circle, parts of it will now be obscured.

Comment: Yes, correct, it's a raster image, the color areas are just a representation for more complex content. Sorry about tagging Illustrator, I was just trying to indicate that any app that can do it is fine with me.

Comment: So, you want to "squish" the light green area" Retain all content but make it fill less area? I think this maybe difficult without some sort of example. The sample image is simple enough that it precludes understanding how the light green area needs to be retained.

Comment: Sadly, I can't show the actual content :( ... Imagine a 2" wooden frame around a round painting. I want to "squish" the frame, so it's 1" wide, but keep the round painting exactly as it was. So the scaling "baseline" is not a single point, but the outline of the painting. That's the problem...

Comment: hmmm...is the content raster or vector? I think I get it now.. a "ring" where the inner circle does not move, but the out circle reduces causing content to scale. *Easy* with a vector ring... not so sure if it's raster based.

Comment: Raster, but I have access to vector software (if it helps) The inner shape is a perfect circle (like the black one above) which at least is better than an irregular shape

Comment: Yes, that's why I was thinking the solution may be some "remapping" of the raster problem into a vector problem

Comment: Wow, someone has the same problem and is even using green rings to illustrate it. I have a psychic twin :) Yes, the solution will work, it just needs to be followed carefully. Thanks.

Comment: Your welcome! Hope we didnt scare you away with the closure.